# Grails belongsTo either class

Tags: grails

I have an Abstract, non-domain class Job:

```
abstract class Job {
    String jobId
    String jobName
    String jobNotes
}
```

Then I have these two domain classes Task and Habit, both of which inherit the Job class:

```
class Task extends Job{
    Date deadline
    int completionTime
}

class Habit extends Job{
    Date rangeStart
    Date rangeEnd
}
```

Now both tasks and habits own one or more Subtasks. Now my problem is that I want the SubTasks to belong to either Task or Habit, which are both subclasses of Job. I tried doing this, but didn't work:

```
class SubTask {
    static belongsTo = {motherJob : Job}
}
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just off the top of my head, but "belongsTo" has more to do with the foreign key relationship in the relational database model than it does the Object-oriented subclass/superclass model.

If you need the subclasses to share a similar type for a design reason, you could have them implement an interface like "JobBehaviour".

Sorry if this is not what you are thinking about.

Comment: I forgot to mention that both classes in my question extend the abstract class Job. how could I use belongsTo so that I can make the subtask belong to either Task or Habit? thanks.

Comment: Try moving Job to domains directory, and use table per subclass  inerentance strategy (if you want one table per domain ) and then keep it static belongsTo = [motherJob : Job]

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the superclass to generate different tables:

```
static mapping = {
    tablePerHierarchy false
}
```

Now you can use FK freely in the subclasses.